# Bing Maps cluster pushpin click

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have a map with clustered pins and I want to make it so that clicking on a clustered pin will zoom the map on that area. I am using the webAPI and have a click handler set up for individual pins. Is there a way that I can set up a click handler for a clustered pin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy to do. The clustering module allows you to pass in a callback function which can be used to customize clustered pushpins. In this callback function you can add a click event to the [clustered pin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Mt712804.aspx). When that event is fired you can then take all the pushpins in the cluster and calculate a bounding box for them to them zoom the map into that area. Note that it is possible that some pushpins may still be in clusters once zoomed in. Here is a code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map, clusterLayer;

    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap',{
            credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
            zoom: 3
        });

        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function () {
            //Generate 3000 random pushpins in the map view.
            var pins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(3000, map.getBounds());

            //Create a ClusterLayer with options and add it to the map.
            clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pins, {
                clusteredPinCallback: customizeClusteredPin
            });
            map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
        });
    }

    function customizeClusteredPin(cluster) {
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(cluster, 'click', clusterClicked);
    }

    function clusterClicked(e) {
        if (e.target.containedPushpins) {
            var locs = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = e.target.containedPushpins.length; i < len; i++) {
                //Get the location of each pushpin.
                locs.push(e.target.containedPushpins[i].getLocation());
            }

            //Create a bounding box for the pushpins.
            var bounds = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs);

            //Zoom into the bounding box of the cluster. 
            //Add a padding to compensate for the pixel area of the pushpins.
            map.setView({ bounds: bounds, padding: 100 });
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```